# How would you model a friendship relationship in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

I know a lot of answers have been given that advise embedding an array of references to other users, but what all answers of this sort neglect is that friendship is a two-way relationship and that when Alice is Bob's friend, Bob is automatically Alice's friend. I'm not modeling followers.

So I don't want to keep two references every time a new user enters the system. I need a model that takes into account the two-way nature of the relationship.

I was thinking a collection of Friendship 'edges' where each document holds a reference to the two users. Wanted to know if literature regarding this already exists out there.

Comment: A pair of IDs where you ignore (in terms of business logic) the order of IDs represents automatically a non-directed edge - only your business logic defines whether the "first" part of a pair is the "follower" and the second part of the edge the "followed".

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB is generally not a good fit for modeling graph relations. There are specialized graph databases which excel at this task.

However, when you do not want to add another database technology to the mix, I would recommend to create a new collection `frienships` and model each friend-relation as a document with an array of two entries, each of them an object with the abbreviated information about one of the users which you need to display an entry in your friend-lists:

```
{
    friendship: [
       {
            id:123,
            name: "Bob",
            avatar: "Bob.jpg"
       },
       {
            id:456,
            name: "Alice",
            avatar: "Alice.jpg"
       }
    ]
}
```

The reason for duplicating information from the user documents in the friendship documents is to avoid a second query to the users collection to obtain all the data for displaying a users friend-list. MongoDB <s>can not do JOINs</s> [can only perform JOINs on unsharded collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), so you should avoid spreading data you need for a specific use-case over multiple collections, even when it means that you create redundancies. Otherwise you would need to perform multiple queries one after another, which slows down the response time of your application significantly.

When you want to get the friend-list of user 123, you would perform a `db.friendships.find({"friendship.id", 123})` (an index on `friendship.id` will improve performance) and then receive a list of documents where Bob is either the first or the second friend.

You would then iterate these documents and output the short info of the array-entry which is *not* user 123.

Alternatively you can filter out the Bob-entries on the database with an aggregation pipeline. Use the $match query above, $unwind the friendship-array and then $match those documents where id is not 123. This would be a trade-off: You conserve bandwidth at the expense of CPU load on the database server.

To query if a friendship-relation already exists, use:

```
db.friendships.find( { $and: [ 
       { "friendship.id": 123 }, 
       { "friendship.id": 456 } 
    ] } ).count();
```

Comment: This answer covers the fact that a friendship is a two-way relationship, though it's not clear why you need to persist the name, avatar fields in the friendship collection documents.

Comment: @DimitrisZorbas Added another paragraph explaining why I recommend this.

Comment: @Seems clear now, there is still some consideration on the introduced redundancies, due to the fact that data consistency is at stake and has to be carefully managed.

Comment: @DimitrisZorbas You need to prioritize consistency vs. performance. In this particular case, consistency is not as important. Take, for example, a user changing their avatar. Yes, many, many friendship documents need to be updated and this is not done atomic, so it will take a while until all friendship lists show the new avatar. But this is a performance-uncritical operation which can be done in the background. The users will not even notice when it takes a few minutes or even hours until all users of the network see the new avatar.