# Best practice to run a mongo update in background?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to this thread: [How would you model a friendship relationship in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703788/how-would-you-model-a-friendship-relationship-in-mongodb) One  of the commentators wrote this:

> (..) You need to prioritize consistency vs. performance. In this particular case, consistency is not as important.Take, for example, a user changing their avatar. Yes, many, many friendship documents need to be updated and this is not done atomic, so it will take a while until all friendship lists show the new avatar. But this is a performance-uncritical operation which can be done in the background. The users will not even notice when it takes a few minutes or even hours until all users of the network see the new avatar.

Im at this point, when I update my profile, that I have to update many many other documents. What would be best practice and how can I run the update task, which updates the many other documents, in background (using node.js + mongoose) like the commentator had described? A Cronjob for example would only run at specific times, but would it fit to this use-case? I would appreciate every information.

Comment: Use a background job process. Your main app pushes a "update user's avatar" to a queue and returns. Then, sometime later, another process picks this job from the queue and runs it. The point is to remove this action from the user's request/response code.

Comment: In ruby we normally use Sidekiq for this. Don't know what's popular in node.js world.

Comment: Got it with "bull" :-), works like a charm.